# The part printed correctly except few layers

Tags: print-quality, creality-ender-3, print-failure

As you can see from the picture, the part is good except some missing layers near the bottom. I have tried to search for this problem but nothing similar appeared. So, what might be the cause and what is the name for this problem?

[image: Photo showing print issue]

- Printer: Ender3, new.
- Slicer: Cura
- Nozzle: 0.4 mm
- Temperature:

  - 200 °C nozzle
  - 50 °C bed
- Material: PLA
- Print speed: 50 mm/s

Comment: Welcome to 3dPrinting.SE! In order to even start considering your problem, we need to know some key things which may not seem important to you. Such as, what type of filament you are using, what are your bed/extruder temps, what slicer you are using, plus whatever else you can think of about the setup and such of the printer you're using. How long have your had your printer? Is it well used? Is this a new issue or does it appear in all of your prints? Please edit your question and insert as much information as you can so we can attempt to help you.

Comment: @PAULSTER2 Thanks, I did not know all of these information are needed, I just updated the question.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like either the nozzle had been clogged for some layers and it resolved itself or the g-code contained incorrect instructions.

I suggest altering your print settings slightly and reslicing, then just printing it again. To get more accuracy on the prints, I suggest a line width of 0.45 mm.